# LINQ on the .NET 2.0 Runtime

Tags: .net, linq, .net-3.5, .net-2.0, clr

Can a LINQ enabled app run on a machine that only has the .NET 2.0 runtime installed?

In theory, LINQ is nothing more than syntactic sugar, and the resulting IL code should look the same as it would have in .NET 2.0.

How can I write LINQ without using the .NET 3.5 libraries? Will it run on .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are some "Hacks" that involve using a System.Core.dll from the 3.5 Framework to make it run with .net 2.0, but personally I would not want use such a somewhat shaky foundation.

See here: [LINQ support on .NET 2.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2007/09/05/linq-support-on-net-2-0.aspx)

> 1. Create a new console application
> 2. Keep only System and System.Core as referenced assemblies
> 3. Set Copy Local to true for System.Core, because it does not exist in .NET 2.0
> 4. Use a LINQ query in the Main method. For example the one below.
> 5. Build
> 6. Copy all the bin output to a machine where only .NET 2.0 is installed
> 7. Run

(Requires .net 2.0 SP1 and I have no idea if bundling the System.Core.dll violates the EULA)

Comment: redistributing System.Core.dll is a violation of Microsoft's license

Comment: after I built and run, there is nothing in bin folder except debug folder. :( I am building Console application in .Net 4.0 visual studio 2010.

Comment: @JonasT If you're on .net 4.0 then this doesn't apply to you at all since it's about .net 2.0 using LINQ. Feel free to ask a separate question, giving details about your setup.

Comment: Thanks Michael. All I am looking for is that output files. I am using .net 2.0. The problem is I am using Visual Studio 2010 which does not produce any output in bin folder. Is there anyway I can download those outputs?

Comment: Licenses and patents violate common sense. There's no idea that was originated in Microsoft. All of them are built on the shoulders of previous inventions. Everything belongs to everyone and I hope one day it'll become obvious. Shift in thinking is a must, otherwise we cannot make it as humanity.

Answer (score 82):

It's weird that no one has mentioned [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx). This little awesome project is a backport of LINQ (IEnumerable, but without IQueryable) and its dependencies (Func, Action, etc) to .NET 2.0. And:

> If your project references LINQBridge
>   during compilation, then it will bind
>   to LINQBridge's query operators; if it
>   references System.Core during
>   compilation, then it will bind to
>   Framework 3.5's query operators.

Comment: +1 I use this a lot. Note: this is an implementation of LINQ to Objects (the IEnumerable extensions), works perfectly if using VS2008 (C# 3.0) targeting framework 2.0+. It is NOT an implementation of LINQ to SQL or other LINQ providers.

Comment: It's bad that LINQBridge doesn't support Linq-2-Xml :( The Linq-2-Xml makes working with Xml easy and nice.

Comment: @Dmitry Linq2Xml is how I get jobs done so quickly. Xpath is still a good alternative but not as fluent.

Comment: I just came across BackLinq http://www.raboof.com/projects/backlinq/ by the same author! Does anyone know what is the difference or which is latest?

Comment: @ala : see http://code.google.com/p/backlinq/ : "BackLINQ sources have been rolled and merged into the LINQBridge project and maintained under its identity. As a result, this project site has been retired and left here for archival purposes. Please follow LINQBridge for further updates, contributions and reporting of issues."

Comment: The one disadvantage of LinqBridge is that it's nearly impossible to use some good mocking framework (like RhinoMocks or Moq) at it's full power when you use LinqBrige as they need reference to System.Core. RhinoMocks is usable but it's best part is unavailable as you can't reference System.Core and LinqBridge at a time.

Comment: @DmitryLobanov : the real problem there is *needing* those libraries.

Comment: If it doesn't support IQueryable (it doesn't), then what's the point ? ? ?

Comment: @Quandary : Func, Action and "LINQ to objects" are very useful on their own. Personally I use them *a lot* more than IQueryables.

Answer (score 11):

In theory yes, provided you distribute the LINQ specific assemblies and any dependencies. However that is in violation of Microsoft's licensing. Scott Hanselman wrote a blog post about [Deploying ASP.NET MVC on ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingASPNETMVCOnASPNET20.aspx) which is similar to what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the LINQ sources from mono (.NET for Linux) to get LINQ running on .NET 2.0.

```
IEnumerable<T> : yes 
IQueryable<T>  : yes
LINQ to XML : has been working in the trunk, but due to further additions, the trunk doesn't compile anymore
```

Someone has done it here:
[LINQ for .NET 2.0](http://linq4you.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 6):

Short answer:

- **LINQ to Objects: yes** (`IEnumerable<T>`)
- **LINQ to SQL/Entities: no** (`IQueryable<T>`)
- LINQ to XML/DataSets: not yet?

---

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173080/c-net-3-0-3-5-features-in-2-0-using-visual-studio-2008) about .Net 3.5 features available automatically or with little effort when targetting .Net 2.0 from VS2008.

Basically, anything that is only "syntax sugar" and the new compilers (C# 3.0, VB 9.0) emit as 2.0-compatible IL will work. This includes many features used by LINQ such as anonymous classes, lambdas as anonymous delegates, automatic properties, object initializers, and collection initializers.

Some LINQ features use classes, interfaces, delegates, and extension methods that live in the new 3.5 assemblies (such as System.Core.dll). Redistributing these assemblies is a license violation, but they could be reimplemented. Using extension methods need only that you declare an empty `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute`. LINQ to Objects relies on `IEnumerable<T>` extensions and several delegate declarations (the `Action<T>` and `Func<T>` families) and have been implemented in [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) (as [mausch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138/linq-on-the-net-2-0-runtime/394595#394595) mentioned). LINQ to XML and LINQ to DataSets rely on LINQ to Objects which I guess could also be implemented for .Net 2.0, but I haven't seen this done yet.

LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities require many new classes (`DataContext`/`ObjectContext`, lots of attributes, `EntitySet<T>`, `EntityRef<T>`, `Link<T>`, `IQueryable<T>`, etc) and expression trees, which, even if somehow reimplemented, will probably require at least .Net 2.0 SP1 to work.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about C#.

I do know, however, that you can write VB LINNQ code w/out the 3.5 libraries as long as you use the VS 2008 compiler to target the 2.0 framework.

You will, however, have to implement some of the LINQ methods your self.

LINQ uses a syntatic transformation to translate queries into executable code. Basically, it will take code like this:

```
dim q = from x in xs where x > 2 select x*4;
```

and convert it into code like this:

```
dim q = xs.where(function(x) x > 2).select(function(x) x * 4);
```

For the LINQ functionality that ships with the 3.5 framework, those methods are implemented as extension methods on either IEnumerable or IQueryable (there's also a bunch of methods that work on data sets too).

The default IEnumerable extension methods are defined in System.Linq.Enumerable and look like this:

```
<Extension()>
public function Select(of T, R)(source as IEnumerable(of T), transform as Func(of T, R)) as IEnumerable(of R)

   'do the transformation...

end function
```

The IQueryable extension methods take expressions trees as arguments, rather than lambdas. They look like this:

```
 <Extension()>
 public function Select(of T, R)(source as IQueryable<T>, transform as Expression(of Func(of T, R))
     'build a composite IQueryable that contains the expression tree for the transformation
 end function
```

The expression tree versions enable you to get a tree representation of the expressions provided to the clauses which can then be used to generate SQL code (or what ever else you want).

You could probably create your own version of LINQ to objects in about a day or so. It's all pretty straight forward.

If you want to use DLINQ, then things would be a little bit more difficult.

Comment: +1, however note that expression trees (for IQueryable) are only available in 3.5+

Comment: .. and yes, everything you said about VB 9.0 applies to C# 3.0 (using new compiler but targetting older fx version)

Comment: But you can write your own expression tree implementation if you like.

Answer (score 3):

No, because while you thought LINQ is really just syntactic sugar, it actually heavily used expression trees -- a feature absent in .NET 2.0.

That being said .NET 3.5 only builds up on top of .NET 2.0, and that's the reason why the IL doesn't look "different" or "special".

I do not see a reason why you shouldn't just install the .NET 3.5 Framework. Everything .NET 2.0 will work fine on it, promise :)

Comment: .Net 3.0 or higher won't install on windows 2000.

Comment: note: expression trees are used by IQueryable (as in LINQ to SQL), but not by IEnumerbale (as in LINQ to Objects)

Comment: Plus, in the "Corporate" world, we literally have machines that have not been "upgraded" to `.NET 2.0`.  Yes.  Seriously, we do.

Comment: Windows XP requires SP3 to install .NET 3.0 or higher and certain devices running Windows XP embedded are not so simple to update.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the LINQ library is only available since the framework 3.0.
If you want to use something similar in the framework 2.0, you would need to rewritte it yourself :) or find a similar third-party library. I only found a bit of information [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2007/09/05/linq-support-on-net-2-0.aspx) but it didn't convinced me either.