# Is List.Find<T> considered dangerous? What's a better way to do List<T>.Find(Predicate<T>)?

Tags: c#, .net

I used to think that [List<T> is considered dangerous](http://galilyou.blogspot.com/2010/07/listfindpredicate-considered-harmful.html). My point is that, I think default(T) is not a safe return value! [Many other people think so too](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/cmexr/thats_why_i_think_listfindpredicatet_is/) Consider the following:

```
List<int> evens = new List<int> { 0, 2, 4, 6, , 8};
var evenGreaterThan10 = evens.Find(c=> c > 10);
// evenGreaterThan10 = 0 #WTF
```

default(T) for value types is 0, hence 0 is goona be returned is the above code segment! 
I didn't like this, so I added an extension method called TryFind that returns a boolean and accepts an output parameter besides the Predicate, something similar to the famous TryParse approach. 
 
Edit: 
Here's my TryFind extension method:

```
public static bool TryFind<T>(this List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate, out T output)  
{  
  int index = list.FindIndex(predicate);  
  if (index != -1)  
  {  
    output = list[index];  
    return true;  
  }  
  output = default(T);  
  return false;  
}
```

What's a your way to do Find on generic Lists?

Comment: Why not just use .Where(c=> c>10)? I'm no expert but that should work..

Comment: @Jouke - *Where()* returns an IEnumerable list, not just the first item found that *Find()* does.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out -- IMHO it is a serious flaw, making Find a no-go solution (luckily there is Where and First). On the other hand Find() should be 100% equivalent to Where().First().

Comment: @macias urw! I actually got bitten with this, so I thought I should share. Right now in my extension method I take advantage of FindIndex! see my edit!

Comment: Nice edit. It is pretty much what I answered execept your return value and params are reversed and my code does one less comparison :)

Answer (score 20):

I don't. I do `.Where()`

```
evens.Where(n => n > 10); // returns empty collection

evens.Where(n => n > 10).First(); // throws exception

evens.Where(n => n > 10).FirstOrDefault(); // returns 0
```

The first case just returns a collection, so I can simply check if the count is greater than 0 to know if there are any matches.

When using the second, I wrap in a try/catch block that handles InvalidOperationException specfically to handle the case of an empty collection, and just rethrow (bubble) all other exceptions. This is the one I use the least, simply because I don't like writing try/catch statements if I can avoid it.

In the third case I'm OK with the code returning the default value (0) when no match exists - after all, I did explicitly say "get me the first **or default**" value. Thus, I can read the code and understand why it happens if I ever have a problem with it.

**Update:**

For .NET 2.0 users, I would **not** recommend the hack that has been suggested in comments. It violates the license agreement for .NET, and it will in no way be supported by anyone.

Instead, I see two ways to go:

1. Upgrade. Most of the stuff that runs on 2.0 will run (more or less) unchanged on 3.5. And there is so much in 3.5 (not just LINQ) that is *really* worth the effort of upgrading to have it available. Since there is a new CLR runtime version for 4.0, there are more breaking changes between 2.0 and 4.0 than between 2.0 and 3.5, but if possible I'd recommend upgrading all the way to 4.0. There's really no good reason to be sitting around writing new code in a version of a framework that has had 3 major releases (yes, I count both 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0 as major...) since the one you're using.
2. Find a work-around to the `Find` problem. I'd recommend either just using `FindIndex` as you do, since the -1 that is returned when nothing is found is never ambiguous, or implementing something with `FindIndex` as you did. I don't like the `out` syntax, but before I write an implementation that doesn't use it, I need some input on what you want returned when nothing was found.
   Until then, the `TryFind` can be considered OK, since it aligns with previous functionality in .NET, for example `Integer.TryParse`. And you do get a decent way to handle nothing found doing

   ```
   List<Something> stuff = GetListOfStuff();
   Something thing;

   if (stuff.TryFind(t => t.IsCool, thing)) { 
       // do stuff that's good. thing is the stuff you're looking for.
   }
   else 
   {
       // let the user know that the world sucks.
   }
   ```

Comment: and what does the poor soul running .net 2.0 have to do?

Comment: @Galilyou - upgrade? ;)  You can use LINQ in .net 2.0 environments, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138/linq-on-the-net-2-0-runtime

Comment: I'm a big user of *FirstOrDefault*, but when using it against value types you end up in the same predicament. Like you said though, it is possibly a better option that using *Find* due to it being more explicit. I wonder how many subtle bugs have been introduced to products due to the default(T) behaviour :)

Comment: @Winston Smith: It is a hack. It is not supported officially. It violates the user licence.

Comment: Why `evens.Where(n => n > 10).First();` instead of just `evens.First(n => n > 10);`?  Surely `Where().First()` would be much slower.

Comment: @Charles: Actually, because how LINQ to Objects is implemented, it won't make much of a difference. Nothing is actually done in the call to `Where` until something calls for an object, which will be when `First` is called. Then, *one and only one* element is processed in the `Where` call, and since `First` will never ask again, `Where` will never be called again and never even try to filter any more results.

Comment: @Charles: Jon Skeet has a very educational (and quite lengthy) blog series about reimplementing LINQ to Objects here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx Definitely worth a look!

Comment: Hey that's cool - thanks. Just to be clear, _is_ there actually a reason to use `Where(n => n > 10).First()` instead of `First(n => n > 10)`?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `Find` you could use `FindIndex`. It returns the index of the element found or `-1` if no element was found.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: I missed the FindIndex in the original post ... nevermind. :)

Answer (score 3):

It is ok if you know there are no `default(T)` values in your list or if the `default(T)` return value can't be the result.

You could implement **your own** easily.

```
public static T Find<T>(this List<T> list, Predicate<T> match, out bool found)
{
    found = false;

  for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
  {
    if (match(list[i]))
    {
            found = true;
      return list[i];
    }
  }
  return default(T);
}
```

and in code:

```
bool found;
a.Find(x => x > 5, out found);
```

Other options:

```
evens.First(predicate);//throws exception
evens.FindAll(predicate);//returns a list of results => use .Count.
```

It depends on what version of framework you can use.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a problem with the default value of T, use Nullable to get a more meaningful default value :

```
List<int?> evens = new List<int?> { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 };
var greaterThan10 = evens.Find(c => c > 10);
if (greaterThan10 != null) 
{
    // ...
}
```

This also requires no additional call of Exists() first.

Answer (score 2):

Doing a call to `Exists()` first will help with the problem:

```
int? zz = null;
if (evens.Exists(c => c > 10))
    zz = evens.Find(c => c > 10);

if (zz.HasValue)
{
    // .... etc ....
}
```

slightly more long-winded, but does the job.

Comment: I had to do this option, none of the other options appeared in C# 4.6 / Visual Studio 2017... Yes, it searches twice, but fixed my problem until I find a better method, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The same answer I gave on Reddit.

```
Enumerable.FirstOrDefault( predicate )
```

Comment: It is exactly what the OP is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Jaroslav Jandek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3202896/4299943) above I would make an extension that returns bool true if match and passes the object in out if match:

```
static class Extension
{
    public static bool TryFind<T>(this List<T> list, Predicate<T> match, out T founditem)
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (match(list[i]))
            {
                founditem = list[i];
                return true;
            }
        }

        founditem = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then it can used on a List object 'a' and called like this using 'out var' syntax:

```
if (a.TryFind(x => x > 5, out var founditem)){
    //enter code here to use 'founditem'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun

```
evens.Where(c => c > 10)
    .Select(c => (int?)c)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(null)
    .First();
```