# Is LINQ available in .net 2.0?

Tags: .net, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ on the .NET 2.0 Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138/linq-on-the-net-2-0-runtime)

Is LINQ available in .net 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

[LINQ on the .NET 2.0 Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138/linq-on-the-net-2-0-runtime)

http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=20295