# LINQ on .Net 1.1

Tags: .net, linq

Can we run a win forms with LINQ in our app using .net 1.1 and Microsoft IDE 2003?

If yes, how?

***I cannot upgrade it because it is a school facility.

Thank you

Comment: I deleted my answer which suggested NLinq, after failed test to import its libraries into a VS2003 project. I believe you have no choice but to migrate to a higher version of .NET framework.

Comment: ...and when their students graduate they'll only be 8 years behind everyone else.

Comment: I bet your school can afford a free (as in "free beer") **[VS 2010 Express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/)** or a free (as in "free gull") **[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)**

Answer (score 4):

No. LINQ is .net 3.5 and even though there are "[hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138/linq-on-the-net-2-0-runtime)" to run it on 2.0, I have never seen it work on 1.1 (hard for me to imagine how it would work anyway without Generics)

Comment: Hard for everybody, no doubt.

Answer (score 2):

No.  LINQ is built on top of compiler and framework features that were not available in .NET 1.1.  This is unlikely to ever work.

There are options to get LINQ to (at least somewhat) work on machines with only .NET 2 installed, such as [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx).  However, those still require a C# 3.0 compiler.  Without the C# language features in C# 3.0, it would be impossible to write LINQ operations in a form at all similar to "LINQ".  They also require generics at a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

No. Linq came with Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not posible. Linq is available since .net framework 3.0. you should migrate you app.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading the framework to 3.0 then you can use LINQ