# Compact Framework 3.5 Set Form parent

Tags: winforms, .net-3.5, compact-framework, parent

In .net Compact Framework 2.0, you could add a form to another forms control array basically parenting the other form.

i.e.`_mainForm.Controls.Add(form);`

This is not allowed in .net cf 3.5 and results in an exception:

`System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr(PAL_ERROR ar)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._SetParent(Control ctlParent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Parent(Control value)`

Is there a workaround or alternative for this? I need to be able to parent a form inside a panel on another form.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to make panel a parent of a form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this contains answer to your question: http://207.46.16.248/en-us/netframework/bb986636.aspx

especially this part:

System.Windows.Forms.Form.Parent

**Description** 
Forms can no longer be parented.

**Previous Behavior**
In .NET Compact Framework 1.0, forms could be parented to any other control
that supported child controls. In .NET Compact Framework 2.0, forms
could be parented to any other form.

**New Behavior**

In the .NET Compact
Framework version 3.5, forms cannot be parented.

Comment: I came across this. I'm hoping to find a workaround or an alternative method.

Comment: well, why you need your form to be parented? it was some time ago when I was dealing with CF 3.5 but I don't recall any problems with forms in my app that I needed to do any explicit magic with my forms

Comment: It's the existing architecture of the system. I'm not looking to redo the system, but in maintaining it wanted to use some linq-y goodness.

Comment: so you need LINQ on .net 2.0? maybe these links will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138/linq-on-the-net-2-0-runtime, http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2007/09/05/linq-support-on-net-2-0.aspx but I think these are rather abount full framework version not compact.

Comment: or, if you have actual requirement to use LINQ, you will talk to whoever is decision maker in your company/project and explain to him/her/them that LINQ is basically .net 3.5 stuff and without moving whole or at least parts of a system into new framework version it will be rather hellish task to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to copy form controls to another form in .NET CF 3.5

```
// Clear old form controls

oldform.Controls.Clear();

// Copy controls from newform to oldform

foreach (Control ctl in newform.Controls)
{
    oldform.Controls.Add(ctl);
}
```

Comment: Thequestion is about adding a form to another form.