# Convert the following Linq to xml to .net 2.0

Tags: c#, xml

I am recently working on a .net 2.0 project I have to read some xml files and replace certain elements value.
Wondering how you do it the following not using linq to xml?

```
 IEnumerable<XElement> cities= xmldoc.Descendants("City")
            .Where(x => x.Value == "London");


        foreach (XElement myElem in cities)
        {
            myElem.ReplaceWith(new XElement("City", "NewCity"));
        }
```

or

```
       var xElement = xdoc.Descendants("FirstName").Where(x => x.Value == "Max").First();
        xElement.ReplaceWith(new XElement("FirstName", "NewValue");
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Read this SO post - LINQ on the .NET 2.0 Runtime http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138/linq-on-the-net-2-0-runtime

Comment: take a look at here http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3489611

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using XmlDocument, like this:

```
string xmlFile = "<xml><data<test /><test /><test /><test /></data></xml>";
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(xmlFile);

var oNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//test");
foreach (var oNode in oNodes)
{
   oNode.InnerText = "bla bla"; 
}

xmlDoc.Save("..path to xml file");
```

(In your case you can use `InnerXml` property of the document)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx

To selectNodes you should pass XPath Query, reference can be found:

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/

Also if you XML contains namespace, you need to use XmlNamespaceManager:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx

Otherwise xpath won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) and query it using `XPath` with [`SelectNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1a732z5.aspx).

It will not be as nice and succint.