# Linq, collections, and a boolean function

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2010, collections, .net-2.0, boolean

I want to do this

```
return array.Any(IsOdd);
```

but instead of an array i have a list of objects where IsOdd takes in the object.Number property as its argument.

I tried this

```
return objectList.Select(x => x.Number).Any(IsOdd);
```

but got this error "'Select' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of myObject)'."

Also my code is actually in VB and I'm using vs 2010 but targeting .net 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated answer**

[There is no official way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138/linq-on-the-net-2-0-runtime) to use LINQ in .NET 2.0, although if you are only interested in LINQ to Objects there's [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) to help.

**Original answer**

First off, you can simply use the other overload of [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) and write

```
return objectList.Any(o => IsOdd(o.Number));
```

And second, this sounds like you have forgot `using System.Linq` in your file -- although in that case, straight calling `Any` would not work either.

Comment: And now it also looks like he's targetting 2.0

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Updated the answer so that it wouldn't look silly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're targeting 2.0, the quick answer is that **.NET 2.0 does not support LINQ or extension methods**.

If you decide you don't want to use **LINQBridge** as @Jon suggests, you can very easily recreate your own `Any` method as follows:

```
public static class MyLINQBridge {
    public delegate TResult Func<T1, TResult>(T1 first);
    public static bool Any<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
        foreach (var item in source) {
            if (predicate(item)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Since you're using VS2010, the **compiler** supports lambda methods and [can support extension methods](http://www.dcomproductions.com/blog/2011/09/adding-extension-method-support-for-net-2-0/), so your final code would look like this:

```
return objectList.Any(o => IsOdd(o.Number));
```