# Read Complex XML

Tags: c#, xml, .net-2.0, linq-to-xml

I have difficulties to read from that xml!  I think `XMLDocument` would help but i don't know how to get value from each element in childNode!

Especially, the childnode which has any childNode Inside like IdList.

XML format :

```
 <sdnEntry>

<programList>
  <program>SDNT</program>
</programList>

<idList>
  <id>
    <uid>6028</uid>
    <idType>NIT #</idType>
    <idNumber>900106267-0</idNumber>
    <idCountry>Colombia</idCountry>
  </id>
  <id>
    <uid>6029</uid>
    <idType>N0T #</idType>
    <idNumber>900106267-1</idNumber>
    <idCountry>Colombian</idCountry>      
  </id>
</idList>
</sdnEntry>
```

Code :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"D:\SDN1.xml");

XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;                

XmlNodeList sdnEntryNodeList = root.GetElementsByTagName("sdnEntry"); 

foreach (XmlNode sdnNode in sdnEntryNodeList)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < sdnEntryNodeList.Count; row++)
    {
        XmlNodeList programListNodeList = sdnNode["programList"].GetElementsByTagName("program");

        foreach (XmlNode programNode in programListNodeList)
        {
            program = programNode.InnerText;
        }

        XmlNodeList idListNodeList = element["idList"].GetElementsByTagName("id");

        foreach (....)
        {

        }
     }       

}
```

The above code , is it good ? otherwise , i will take all your advice, please comment ....

How to read programList and idList in That complex XML ?

Comment: Your xml is not complex.. google for **linq to xml**

Comment: Can you post the code you are trying to use so that people can better understand your question. Also please don't use so many !!!! ;)

Comment: Isn't this the same XML I told you once before is not complex? Please show the code you're trying and tell us what specific problem you're having.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar : **ling to xml** , is it support for C# 2.0 ?

Comment: @FrancisUpton : `Sorry for "!!!" , next time i will paste code on the question , but i already comfirm that i used `XMLDocument`

Comment: @JohnSaunders : previous question , i was waiting you to answer but you didn't answer. i hope you try for me , please do me a fever. thank you.

Comment: "Favor", not "Fever". And LINQ to XML is not supported in .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use XMLDocument , here is a sample for you

```
var programList = doc.SelectNodes("/sdnEntry/programList/program");
var idList = doc.SelectNodes("/sdnEntry/idList/id");
```

Comment: `var` is not supported in C# 2.0 (VS2005) . 
What about the my code (above code) , am i good ? or i need to change to your code . thank you....

Comment: `programList` and `idList` got nothing after test .

Comment: It runs in my test. I think you have namespace .

Comment: if you delete yours namespace , it could run.  so ,you must add yours namespace in the code .

Answer (score -2):

Use **linq to xml.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397976.aspx

**Sample:**

```
foreach(var node in doc.Elements("idList").Elements("id").Elements("uid"))
```

Comment: `Use linq to xml.` , is it support for C# 2.0 , VS2005

Comment: It is not .net 2.0. But, there are workaround (rather) hacks available to make ling run in .net 2.0. see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138/linq-on-the-net-2-0-runtime or you can use http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx

Comment: DO you have another way ? hacks is not good for me . because i developer software for commercial ....

Answer (score -2):

I would simplify you code with the following linq-to-xml queries.

```cs
var programs = from program in 
               doc.Root.Element("programList").Descendants("program")
               select program.Value;

var ids = from id in doc.Root.Element("idList").Descendants("id")
          select new
          {
               uid = (string)id.Element("uid"),
               idType = (string)id.Element("idType"),
               idNumber = (string)id.Element("idNumber"),
               idCountry = (string)id.Element("idCountry")
          };
```