# DataView : Upper the strings and distinct them?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dataview

I have this code :

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack=False id="nation" runat="server" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="Desc"></asp:DropDownList>

DataView nation = new DataView(new MyObjects().RsTable);
nation.Sort = "Title DESC";
DropNazioni.DataSource = nation;
DropNazioni.DataBind();
```

What I'd like to do is :

1. Put only distinct values in the DropDownList (so if I have 2 values "Italy", insert only one time Italy);
2. Upper the strings in the DropDownList (so if I have Italy, print ITALY);

Tried `nation.Distinct()` or `nation.ToUpperString()` but seems that these methods don't exists.

I'm on (unfortunatly) an old project, with .NET 2.0, so no LINQ.

Comment: LINQ on the .NET 2.0 Runtime - Take look at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138/linq-on-the-net-2-0-runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution :

```
DropNazioni.DataSource = nation.ToTable(true,new string[] { "Title", "Desc" });
```

and CSS on DropDownList :

```
style="text-transform:uppercase;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `GroupBy`.

```
var result = MyObjects().RsTable
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .GroupBy(p => p.Field<string>("Nation"))
                        .Select(p=>p.Key);
```

Or

```
var result = MyObjects().RsTable
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .GroupBy(p => p.Field<string>("Nation").ToUpper())
                        .Select(p=>p.Key);
```

Comment: DataTabel doesnt contain a definition of AsEnumerable() (I'm on .NET 3.5)

Comment: @markzzz - It is there  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Damn! Sorry! I'm on an old project, .NET 2 :( That's why I can't use also linq...