# .Net 2.0 Searching for member Object in a generic list

Tags: c#, list, generics, search

I am using.Net 2.0

I have a generic

```
List< MyContainerObject > MyList;
```

and

```
MyContainerClass MyContainerObject = new MyContainerClass();
```

and

```
Public Class MyContainerClass
{
    public BasicClass BasicObject;
    public AdvanceClass AdvanceObject
}
```

How can I search for BasicObject in MyList efficiently?

Sample Code added

```
namespace WindowsApplication4
{
    public class Program
    {
        private List<ContainerClass> MyList;
        public Program()
        {
            MyList = new List<ContainerClass>();
        }

        private void Add(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ContainerClass objContainer1 = new ContainerClass("B1","A1");
            ContainerClass objContainer1 = new ContainerClass("B2", "A2");
            MyList.Add(objContainer1);
            MyList.Add(objContainer2);            
        }
        private void Get(BasicClass objBasic)
        {
            //How to retreive ContainerClass from MyList that has objBasic ??
        }
    }

    public class ContainerClass
    {
        private BasicClass BasicObject;
        private AdvancedClass AdvancedObject;
        public ContainerClass(string baseID, string AdvanceID)
        {
            BasicObject = new BasicClass();
            BasicObject.ID = baseID;
            AdvancedObject = new AdvancedClass();
            AdvancedObject.ID = AdvanceID;
        }

    }

    public class BasicClass
    {
        public  string ID;
        public int name;
    }

    public class AdvancedClass
    {
        public string ID;
        public int name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it really so difficult to provide something that at least compiles? Even if it is just for demonstration purposes, you would show a minimum effort then.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "search for BasicObject". Every item in MyList will have a BasicObject field.

Comment: What do you mean by "search" and "efficiently"?

Answer (score 1):

```
var found = MyList.FirstOrDefault(o => o.BasicObject == someObject);
```

Note that unless BasicObject implement `IEquatable<BasicObject>` and/or overloads `Equals`/`operator==` you end up with `object.ReferenceEquals(o.BasicObject, someObject)` effectively.

Oops. .NET 2.0. Well:

```
BasicObject FindBy(List<MyContainerClass> list, BasicObject o)
{
     foreach (MyContainerClass i in list)
     {
          if (i.BasicObject == o) // same caveats on Equality
              return i;
     }
     return null;
}
```

Comment: .net 2.0 doesn't know much about linq... (not the downvoter by the way)

Comment: I missed that. That's not entirely true by the way. CLR and C# are versioned independently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2147/85371

Comment: LINQ would work in C# 2.0, but you'll have to ditch the extension methods and lambdas for the more verbose static method calls and anonymous delegates.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be very nice if you would be using .Net version higher than 2.0 than you caould use the linq to simply get the object you want rom the list.

but you can use delegate and find method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx

could be something like

```
      MyContainerClass MyContainerObject  = MyList.Find(delegate(MyContainerClass p) {return
 BasicObject.Val == someval; });
```