# Result Set Stored on Models - C# .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, model, resultset

I have a function that gets the data in the database. Below are the code.

```
        public DataTable getAllTransaction(OleDbConnection conn)
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter oleAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            string query = "";
            DataTable tblResult = new DataTable();

            query = @"SELECT t.id AS `Transaction ID`,
                                  c.id AS `Client ID`,
                                  c.clientname AS `Client Name`,
                                  t.cashvalue AS `Cash Value`,
                                  t.amount AS `Amount`,
                                  t.transdate AS `Transaction Date`,
                                  t.remarks AS `Remarks`
                             FROM client AS c 
                            INNER JOIN `transaction` AS t 
                               ON c.id=t.clientid";
            oleAdapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            oleAdapter.Fill(tblResult);

            return tblResult;
        }
```

My problem is, how could I store the result set into model (e.g. I don't want to return DataTable). Below is my Model Class.

```
Class TransactionModel
{
    public int transID { get; set; }
    public int clientID { get; set; }
    public string clientName { get; set; }
    public double cashValue { get; set; }
    public double amout { get; set; }
    public DateTime transDate { get; set; }
    public string remarks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just a general comment for all answers, LINQ isn't readily available for .NET 2. You'd have to do some form of a hack as I understand? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138/linq-on-the-net-2-0-runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `LINQ` and do:

```
var tranModel = from r in tblResult.Tables[0]
                select new TransactionModel 
                {
                   transId = r.Field<int>("transID"),
                   clientId = r.Field<int>("clientId"),
                   clientName = r.Field<string>("ClientName")
                }
```

Note since you are using `.NET 2.0.` LINQ is not directly available.  You will have to use
Something like `LINQBridge`:  http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx

Another alternative is to loop through all of the rows in `tblResult` and have a generic list of `TransactionModel`.  For instance:

```
 List<TransactionModel> tModels = new List<TransactionModel>();
 foreach (var row in tblResult.Tables[0].Rows) 
 {
     tModels.Add(new TransactionModel 
                 {
                   transId = row["TransId"],
                   clientId = row["ClientId"],     
                   clientName = row["clientName"]
                 });
 }
```

Comment: `LINQ` isn't available in .NET 2, is it?

Comment: @LukeHennerley very good point! OP will have to use something like LINQBridge

Comment: Is it ideally to use Models instead of manipulating data from DataTable? What are the benefits if I used model instead of DataTable and what is the down side?

Comment: @Bryan - using a model provides a more concrete type.  Also passing a model around is a lot cleaner than passing a DataTable.

Answer (score 2):

**Because LINQ isn't available in .NET 2**, you'd have to loop through the items yourself and transform them into your type. Something like this:

```
DataTable transactions = getAllTransactions();
List<TransactionModel> model = new List<TransactionModel>();

foreach (DataRow transaction in transactions.Rows)
{
    TransactionModel tran = new TransactionModel
                            {
                                transId = transaction.Field<int>("transID"),
                                clientId = transaction.Field<int>("clientId"),
                                clientName = transaction.Field<string>("ClientName")
                                //etc...
                            };

    model.Add(tran);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like:

```
List<TransactionModel> TransactionItems = tblResult.AsEnumerable().Select(r => 
new TransactionModel
    {
        transID  = r.Field<int>("TransactionID"),
        clientID = r.Field<int>("clientID"),
        and so on.....
    }).ToList();

return items;
```