# LINQ in Framework 2.0

Tags: c#

I want to use LINQ in Framework 2.0. IS it possible?

Also i heard from someone that Microsoft will stop the Support of Framework 2.0 and below.

Is it right?

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138/linq-on-the-net-2-0-runtime

Comment: Ramdas bhau framework upgrade karun ka ghet nahi? mazz uttar pan ekada refer kara.

Comment: @Freelancer Kay Karnar Client framework 2.0 use karato ajun sudhha. I want to upgrade the performance of my application which is already developed in 2.0 and i thought that i will use LINQ to avoid the big loops whicg are avaialbe in code.

Comment: chalayachach. mi dilelya links follow kara. nakkich upyog hoil. Jai maharashtra

Answer (score 1):

Try to refer this link>>

http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2007/09/05/linq-support-on-net-2-0.aspx

you will get all the things here.

We can use the LINQ sources from mono (.NET for Linux) to get LINQ running on .NET 2.0.

Also refer this one>>

http://linq4you.codeplex.com/