# Difference in Arrays

Tags: c#, winforms

If I have an `array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)`
and another `array (2,4,6)`

How do I get a third `array (1,3,5,7,8)`?

I can't use LINQ, I'm working on .NET CF 2.0. 
How can I do this without using LINQ or is there a LINQ resource compatible with .NET CF 2.0?

Comment: Use some simple looping logic?

Comment: [Linq on the .NET 2.0 Runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138/linq-on-the-net-2-0-runtime)

Comment: You can use nested for loop. Compare the values, end exclude the equal ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will be the shortest answer :)

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int[] arr2 = new int[] { 2, 4, 6 };

// copy the content of arr1 into a temporary List
List<int> temp = new List<int>(arr1);
// kick-out unneeded elements from temporary List
foreach (int toRemove in arr2) temp.Remove(toRemove);

// it's done
int[] result = temp.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thats nice! I like it! Can be a bit hard to read, but ... just add comments ennit!

Comment: @No1_Melman I like this one, especially as it is so short. But I can't use `var` either. Yeah I know, it sucks. But I'm developing for a somewhat old handheld device and that is the main issue.

Comment: I have updated my answer again. I forget that .NET CF 2.0 still don't have var statement.

Comment: @ThisUser `var` isn't a big issue, just replace with the type.

Answer (score 2):

For each element of the first array you check whether the second array contains it. If it doesn't then you add it to the result:

```
var array1 = new[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
var array2 = new[] { 2,4,6 };

var result = new List<int>();

foreach (var value1 in array1)
{
    bool exists = false;

    foreach (var value2 in array2)
    {
        if (value1 == value2)
        {
            exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!exists)
    {
        result.Add(value1);
    }
}

// result is { 1,3,5,7,8 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var intList = new List<int>();
for (var i = 0; i < mainArray.Length; i++) // loop through the first array
{
    var exists = false;

    for (var y = 0; y < otherArray.Length; y++) // loop through the next array
    {
        if (mainArray[i] != otherArray[y]) // if the values arent equal
        {
            exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!exists)
    {
        intList.Add(mainArray[i]); // put them in the new list
    }
}
```

Here is the foreach method:

```
foreach (var main in mainArray)
{
    foreach (var other in otherArray)
    {
         // same logic as above
    }
}
```

Comment: Logic is fundamentally flawed. Just run with a sample data and test yourself.

Comment: Example: `main` item `2`. First `other` item is also `2`, so you don't add it to `intList`. But then you go to the second `other` item `4`. Now `2 != 4` and you add `2`.

Comment: Yeah just saw the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is only a simplified way of looping through elements in an enumerable.

Follow this pseudo code:

```
declare result
foreach item in array1
   if array2 does not contain item
      add item to result
```