# VB - Had a function working, doesn't anymore

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

***EDIT:*** Ok, it's because I'm using 2.0 Framework. Any ideas how I can modify that area or alternatives? I have to, unfortunately, stick with 2.0

```
Dim dir2 As New DirectoryInfo("d:\input")
    Dim sw2 As New StreamWriter("d:\input\reportCond.txt")
    For Each fi2 As FileInfo In dir2.GetFiles("report.txt")
        Dim sr2 As New StreamReader(fi2.FullName)
        While Not sr2.EndOfStream
            Dim sLine As String = sr2.ReadLine
            Dim myPath As String = sLine
            Dim fileName As String =System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myPath)
            Dim letters As String = fileName.Where(Function(c) Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray
            Dim comp As String = sLine.Substring(28)
            sw2.WriteLine(letters)
        End While
    Next
```

The Code above was working fine yesterday, today it doesn't and I can't figure out why. The only difference was yesterday I ran it on VS2013, today it doesn't work on VS2010.

I get an error on Function saying "expression expected"

And another one on sw2.WriteLine(letters) saying "Name 'letters' is not declared.

Comment: Just to confirm: you are sure that d:\input\ contains one or more files named report.txt and those files contain some text and each line is at least 28 chars long.

Comment: Also, to clarify, are you getting a run-time error or it won't even compile and run?

Comment: @tgolisch, yes, file is in the location, and text is longer than 28 chars. but it won't run, getting the errors on the error list.

Comment: I got a feeling you were Option Explicit Off and now you have it On.

Comment: ... and which version of .Net are you targeting in each instance?

Comment: @the_lotus, tried it but didn't change.

Comment: @ChicagoMike, using 2.0

Comment: @Gmac There is [no LINQ in .NET 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2138/11683), have to use v3.5+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how the linq `Where` part can be replaced to get the letters variable - which contains characters from the file name.

```
dim c as char
Dim letters As String 
for each c in s
    if char.IsLetter(c)
        letters += c
    end if
next
```

Comment: Will for each work in 2.0? If not a regular for will do the job.

Comment: In VB .Net, you probably want to use `&=` instead of `+=` for string concatenation.  `StringBuilder` class would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `StringBuilder` class to build the string:

```
    Dim dir2 As New DirectoryInfo("d:\input")
    Dim sw2 As New StreamWriter("d:\input\reportCond.txt")
    For Each fi2 As FileInfo In dir2.GetFiles("report.txt")
        Dim sr2 As New StreamReader(fi2.FullName)
        While Not sr2.EndOfStream
            Dim sLine As String = sr2.ReadLine
            Dim myPath As String = sLine
            Dim fileName As String =System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myPath)

            ' Build string
            Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
            For Each c As Char In fileName
                If Char.IsLetter(c) Then
                    sb.Append(c)
                End If
            Next

            Dim comp As String = sLine.Substring(28)

            ' Here's the string you built
            Dim letters As String = sb.ToString()
            sw2.WriteLine(letters)
        End While
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

A .Net 2.0 framework alternative to the `Where` extension method could be:

```
Dim letters As String = Array.FindAll(fileName.ToCharArray(), AddressOf Char.IsLetter)
```

This will create a new array of chars whose elementes will be all chars of `fileName.ToCharArray` for wich `Char.IsLetter` is `True`